# How many ring homomorphisms they are?

Tags: ring-theory

How many ring homomorphisms there are: $$\phi:\mathbb{Z}_{16}\to \mathbb{Z}_{20}$$
So from exercises that I saw I want to say only the trivial, and that makes them 2, but is the id here a homomorphism?

Because $\phi(17)=\phi(1)=1\pmod{20}$ ,but $\phi(17)=17\pmod{20}$

**Edited**: that are rings and we are looking for homomorphisms of rings. Sorry everybody for the mistake.

Comment: Group homomorphism, you presumably mean?

Comment: Hint: there is no reason $\phi(1)=1$ in a group homomorphism of additive groups - then $\phi(0)=0$, because $0$ is the identity.

Comment: If @ThomasAndrews is right below, we are looking for **group** homomorphisms, $\mathbf Z_{16}^\times \to \mathbf Z_{20}^\times$.

Comment: No, I edited, those are rings and we are looking for ring homom'

Comment: Then the answer is $0$.

Comment: The zero homom' is a ring homom', so that is at least one, isn't it ? 
But as i said it's written 2 in the answer, so who is the second, if that isn't a mistake?

Comment: You you define rings as having identities or not? Because there is a non-zero ring homomorphism of $\mathbb Z_{16}\to\mathbb Z_{20}$.

Comment: Note, by the way, how much time you wasted of a lot of people volunteering to help you because you were not clear about your question. At first, your question wasn't specific about what sort of homomorphism, but the tags suggested group homomorphisms. You did not include in the question that you were given an answer, so we did not have that as a basis for figuring out that your question was incomplete. Then you explicitly made the question about group homomorphisms, wasting people's time again. The key to not wasting people's time is to give us as much information as you have.

Comment: In the question it doesn't said anything about identities, but I think it is with them.  But if the written answer is 2 and the non-zero ring homom' is the second, it fit's, right ?
You right, I consider it and will be more careful next time.

Comment: How is the word "ring" defined in your book/class? That will tell us, not the text of the question.

Comment: At the beginning we defined ring without identity, so ring with identity was written by full descreption "ring with identity", but in advanced point all the rings that we looked were by defenition with identities, so it is hard to say for surely here.

Comment: The tags you have selected also do not make much sense, since they are all to do with groups and group homomorphisms rather than rings.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. Let $\phi$ be any homomorphism, we must have then as $16\cdot 1 = 0$ in $\mathbf Z/(16)$ that $16\phi(1) = 0$. That is $\phi(1)$ has to be a multiple of $5$, or $\phi(1) \in \{0,5,10,15\}$. If $\phi(1)$ is known, as $\mathbf Z/(16)$ is generated by $1$, $\phi$ is known.

Comment: Ok, so to each $\phi(1)={0,5,10,15}$ it is homomorphism ? 
But the right answer is only 2, as I know.

Comment: @Ilya.K. Where do you know that from?

Comment: That is the answer in the original exam which was checked by a lecturer (proff.) but maybe it is a mistake, it happens eather. So we need to make sure that all the 4 are homomorphisms, because it is written in the book that, there are only 2.

Comment: They are all, there are 4 homomorphisms.

Comment: If the answer given is $2$, then either  (1) it is wrong or (2) you have the question wrong. Is it possible the question is about isomorphisms between the multiplicative groups of $\mathbb Z_{16}$ and $\mathbb Z_{20}$? Those two groups are isomorphism and there are two isomorphisms...

Comment: Thomas, thank you for your exact interpretation of my mistake, those are rings indeed.

Comment: So. now it must be only 2 right ? 
Only the id and the zero homom' (although I stil don't understand why the id here is a ring homom')?

Answer (score 0):

Homomorphisms $\;\phi\colon\mathbf Z/m\mathbf Z\to\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z$  correspond exactly to homomorphisms $\;\widetilde\phi\colon\mathbf Z\to\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z$ that vanish on $m\mathbf Z$.

As such a homomorphism is determined by the choice of $a+n\mathbf Z=\widetilde\phi(1)$, this means $a$ must be such that $ma\in n\mathbf Z$, i.e. $a\in \dfrac nd\mathbf Z$. Thus:
$$\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbf Z}\bigl(\mathbf Z/m\mathbf Z,\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z\bigr)\simeq (n/d\mathbf Z)/n\mathbf Z\simeq\mathbf Z/d\mathbf Z.$$

In the present case, a homoporphism is determined by the choice of
$$\phi(a+16\mathbf Z)=\begin{cases}20\mathbf Z\\5+20\mathbf Z\\10+20\mathbf Z\\15+20\mathbf Z\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

You can count the number of homomorphisms $\def\Z{\mathbb{Z}}\Z_{16}\to\Z_{20}$ by counting the homomorphisms $f\colon\Z\to\Z_{20}$ such that $\ker f\supseteq 16\Z$ (this follows from the homomorphism theorem).

A homomorphism $f\colon\Z\to\Z_{20}$ is defined just by arbitrarily specifying $f(1)\in\Z_{20}$ and setting $f(n)=nf(1)$, for all $n\in\Z$. So you just need that $f(16)=16f(1)=0+20\Z$, because this is the condition that $16\Z\subseteq\ker f$. Write $f(1)=x+20\Z$, with $0\le x<20$; then you need
$$
16x\in 20\Z
$$
that's the same as $4x\in 5\Z$, which forces $x\in 5\Z$. So the possibilities for $x$ are $0$, $5$, $10$ and $15$ and each one of these choices provides a homomorphism.

Answer (score -1):

Let $[p]_m$ denote the equivalence class of $p$ modulo $m$.

The key here is that any group homomorphism satisfies 
$$
\phi(g)^n = \phi(g^n)
$$
In this case, that tells us that for any integer $n$,
$$
\phi([n]_{16}) = \phi(n \cdot [1]_{16}) = n\phi([1]_{16})
$$
Note, however, that $[0]_{16} = [16]_{16}$, which necessarily means that
$$
\phi([16]_{16}) = \phi([0]_{16}) = [0]_{20}
$$
In particular, we cannot have $\phi([16]_{16}) = [16]_{20}$.

---

The reason that there are three group homomorphisms is that our only options for $\phi([1]_{16})$ are
$$
\phi([1]_{16}) = [0]_{20}\\
\phi([1]_{16}) = [10]_{20}\\
\phi([1]_{16}) = [5]_{20}\\
\phi([1]_{16}) = [15]_{20}
$$
See if you can figure out why this is the case.

Comment: That sounds right, we do have the trivial $\phi(n)=0$ homomorphism, but the right answer as I know is that there are 2 such homomorphisms, including the zero homom', I'm ondering which is the second ?

Comment: There should be $3$ in total, not $2$.

Comment: You are missing $\phi([1]_{16}) = [15]_{20}$.

Comment: @martini good catch

Comment: @Ilya.K. sorry, that's $4$ in total